# Amazon inspector

Tags: amazon-web-services, inspector

I would like to use AWS tool, like in topic. To me it looks like there are two releases of this tool. One with AWS agent installed on EC2 instance, allows tracking security issues. New one with some benchmarking, and so on. So I'm interested in the new one.

I've red docs, set up sample, test env. but still it looks a bit unclear for me. I understand that they are using public [database of vulnerabilities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_cves.html). As well as benchmarking, or testing against best practices.

The question is - how can I know that all of that is tested in lowest 15min. target? Or in the other words - if time is short - what is less tested?

Is anyone use this tool and would like to share knowledge, insights?

Answer (score 0):

A report provided at the end of the testing gives you an overview of the scanning results. The results indicates which of your preselected resources has security issues.

Comment: are you using it? That is quite new product, and I would like to find someone who uses it, and to know that I get something for the money, not only feeling that since I've payed all has to be OK.

Comment: I am not using it directly though I am also interested in it and have done some research as to how it works and also made a few comparisons with similar alternatives. You can also take advantage of the initial free use trial period as mentioned here - https://aws.amazon.com/inspector/pricing/. You can even use it in conjunction with other products -https://aws.amazon.com/inspector/partners/